# Prevent response from NodeJS and Sockei.io before login

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Before a client has acquired a session cookie I wish to prevent NodeJS from responding to connection attempts unless a request is made for the /login url. I've added the following listener to close the socket at the time of a request:

```
server.listeners("request").unshift (request, response)->
  if(request and request.url == "/login")
    # Set /login as the only entrance point to the server
    # A session cookie will be set here
  else
    # Authenticate based on the session cookie
    # if the session is invalid or doesn't exist abort the connection
    request.connection.destroy()
```

Is this solution sufficient to do what I want or will the server make any attempt to negotiate with the client or otherwise respond before the time of the request? I use https and a websocket through socket.io on the same port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the server will still respond to an ssl handshake for any connection, which means that my solution is not sufficient. I'll look into it and might create a separate question on how to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0):

By the time a request has been made, the server has already been accepting data from the client.  There is nothing you can do about this, but unless you are concerned about someone flooding you with data, then this isn't much of a problem.

What you have is sufficient for what you ask, but keep in mind that the security of your solution heavily depends on that session validation.  In particular, it would be wise to prevent a session from being opened by a different IP address than the one it was originally started on.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what happens before the “request” event is triggered in this case? The authentication will be provided by an external single-sing-on service, with server side verification. Given that the session is initialized over https, would checking the origin IP address add to the security of the system? I'm under the impression that the IP address could easily be masked.

Comment: Yes, requests can come from other IP addresses, especially in the case where users are behind NAT or share a proxy.  But, you should still use them.